# Find the least positive integers $n>1$ such that $n\mid 2^{n-1}+3$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

> Find the smallest integers $n>1$ such that $n\mid 2^{n-1}+3.$

I find $n=13957196317$ works, but I wonder if this is the smallest one.

Here is my method:

If $n$ is prime, then $2(2^{n-1}+3)\equiv 2^n+6\equiv 2+6\equiv8 \mod n,$ hence $n=2,$ false.

If $n=pq$ where $p,q$ are both odd prime numbers, then
$$2^{n-1}+3\equiv 2^{p-1}+3\equiv 0 \mod q\\2^{n-1}+3\equiv 2^{q-1}+3\equiv 0 \mod p,$$

factorizing $2^{p-1}+3$ we get some prime factors $q$, if $p\mid 2^{q-1}+3$ then $n=pq$ is a solution.

In this way I get $n=61\times 228806497$ and $n=67\times 44210291368986343.$

PS: We can prove that $GCD(n,30)=1$.

There is no solution up to $n=10^8$, this is my Mathematica code(up to $n=10^7$):

```
Do[If[GCD[n,15]==1 && PowerMod[2,n-1,n]==n-3, Print[n]; Break[]], {n,3,10^7,2}]
```

---

**Updates:**

Gammatester says no solutions till $n\lt2^{31}-1$

Comment: no results upto $n=3\times10^6$

Comment: @Sabyasachi I searched upto $n=10^7.$

Comment: Okay. this is  a interesting problem.

Comment: what language? can you post your code in the question? I am using python.

Comment: favourited and +1ed.

Comment: @Sabyasachi Now upto $n=10^8,$ see my code in the question.

Comment: Cross posted code related part to [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22481014/checking-divisibility-of-numbers)

Comment: I have a feeling brute forcing won't help much here. Need some mathematical perspective.

Comment: @Sabyasachi: I found no solution for $n < 2^{31}-1 = 2.147483648\times10^9.$ I checked if `powermod(2,n-1,n)+3` is zero mod n using native 32/64-bit arithmetic.

Comment: @gammatester ah. okay. i am adding that into the question.

Comment: @gammatester $2^{31}$ is very close to $13957196317$, can you run your program until reached this upper bound?

Comment: Unfortunately going above $2^{31}$ will be much more time consuming, because I would have to use multi-precision arithmetic (the native program needed 880 secs for the 31-bit range).

Comment: By quadratic reciprocity, every prime factor $p$ of $n$ must be of the form $p\equiv 1 \bmod 3$.

Comment: http://oeis.org/A050259

Comment: @user58697 this is $2^{n-1}$ close but different. Plus that is $\pmod 3$ this is $\pmod n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22497659/2855159) on my SO post, has confirmed that $13957196317$ is indeed the first value.

Comment: I must also say that I got the same result with C code!(using GMP too)